# How to use React Router's Link with a variable pathname?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use react router's Link to pass state to another Route's component. Upon attempting to use the pathname with a variable I receive an error – TypeError: string.substr is not a function.

```
{props.groups.map((group) =>
                    <Link to={{
                        pathname: `/groups/${group.uid}`,
                        state: { pass: group }
                      }}>
                        <li>{group.name}</li>
                        <p>{group.activeGame}</p>
                    </Link>
 )}
```

Where `group.uid` is a string e.g.: ENkrRUicMoXdTeGpQRe5.

I expected this to link to '/groups/:groupuid', but receive a `TypeError: string.substr is not a function` citing node_modules/@reach/router/es/lib/utils.js:5:

```
 var startsWith = function startsWith(string, search) {
> 5 |   return string.substr(0, search.length) === search;
  6 | };
```

Comment: What is `group.uid`? Do we have an example?

Comment: group.uid is a string e.g.: `ENkrRUicMoXdTeGpQRe5`

Comment: Do you have an actual page or a route can handle this request?

Comment: A Router is setup to render a component: `<Group path="groups/:groupId" user={user}/>`

Comment: What is in your `<Group>` component? I think the problem lies in it.

Answer (score 0):

To pass object as `props`, you can do this,

```
<Link to={{
     pathname: `/groups/${group.uid}`,
     query: { pass: JSON.stringify(group} }
}}>
    <li>{group.name}</li>
    <p>{group.activeGame}</p>
</Link>
```

And while accessing `props`, you should do this,

```
JSON.parse(this.props.pass)
```